# Assert.state deprecated in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, assert

I trying to delete a file which located at `Desktop/outputs/`

```
public class FileDeleteTasklet implements Tasklet,InitializingBean {

    @Value("${fileName}")
    private String fileName;

    @Value("home/xxx/Desktop/outputs/")
    private Resource directory;


    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution sc, ChunkContext cc) throws Exception {

        String file = fileName+ time()+".csv";
        try {
            File dir = directory.getFile();
            Assert.state(dir.isDirectory());

            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

                if (files[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(file)) {
                    boolean rename = files[i].delete();
                    if (!rename) {
                        System.out.println("Could not delete");
                        throw new UnexpectedJobExecutionException("Could not delete file " + files[i].getPath());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(files[i].getPath() + " is deleted!");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("=========== Could not delete file " + file+ " *** failed *** due to " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
         Assert.notNull(directory, "directory must be set");
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
=========== Could not delete file Reporting_2018-02-22.csv *** failed *** due to [Assertion failed] - this state invariant must be true
```

I realize `Assert.state deprecated` in Java ? Is it why the error happened ?

Comment: Just check your code with the non deprecated function. `Assert.state(dir.isDirectory(), "Any message you want")`

Comment: `Assert.state()` isn't *in* Java. It is part of Spring. Hard to see why you're traversing an entire directory just to delete a file whose name you already know, or why a `boolean` resulting from a deletion is called `rename`.

Comment: @EJP I follow this [article](http://walkingtechie.blogspot.my/2017/03/spring-batch-tasklet-example.html)

Comment: Why? That code delete all the files. If you already know the filename you don't need to waste time and space listing the directory. He doesn't say it is 'in Java' either. Also hard to see the point of the assertion, when the condition could become true any time. It isn't a true invariant.

Comment: @Patrick If I add a message (Yes), I get `Could not delete file Reporting_2018-02-22.csv *** failed *** due to Yes`

Comment: @EJP If the file exists in directory, it will delete.

Comment: Of course it will, and so will `new File(file).delete()`, without the wasteful directory search, assuming  you can  control the case invariance, which you should be able to do. This also gets rid of the assertion completely. You're allowed to write your own code, you know. Cut and paste isn't a guarantee of anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't why the error happened. The error happened because it wasn't a directory, just like the code says.

But you don't need the assert (which should never have been an assertion in the first place, as it isn't an invariant of the code), or the pointless and wasteful directory search either. Just use

```
boolean deleted = new File(file).delete();
```

assuming you can control the case issue, which you should be able to do.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `isDirectory()` says

> true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a directory; false otherwise

So I'm going to assume that the folder does not exist.

The assert failing is not related to the deprecation.
Looking at the javadocs for SpringBoot5, it says:

> Deprecated. as of 4.3.7, in favor of state(boolean, String)

[ref.](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/5.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Assert.html#state-boolean-)